# How to dispatch response data from api in react redux?

Tags: reactjs, json, redux

when the user logs in I can get the following Json data.

Json

```
{
    "hubs": [
        "111.com",
        "222.com",
        "333.com",
}
```

The section of code below

```
  console.log(response.data.hubs[0])
  console.log(response.data.hubs[1])
  console.log(response.data.hubs[2])
```

I can see the URL like

```
"111.com", "222.com", "333.com",
```

in console.

However, I use dispatch, stores and useSelector, I got the error like this.
[image]

I don't know why I got the error.

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Login.js

```
const Login = () => {

  const history = useHistory();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [cookies, setCookie] = useCookies();
  const { register, handleSubmit, watch, errors } = useForm();

  const getJwt = async (data) =>{

        const email_encoded = btoa(data.email)
        const password_encoded = btoa(data.password)
        await axios.get('xxx.com', {
          auth: {
            username: data.email,
            password: data.password,
          }
          })
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log("logged in!");
          setCookie('accesstoken', response.data.token, { path: '/' }, { httpOnly: true });
          setCookie('refreshtoken', response.data.refresh_token, { path: '/' }, { httpOnly: true });
          console.log(response.data.hubs[0])
          console.log(response.data.hubs[1])
          console.log(response.data.hubs[2])
          dispatch(setMCUHouse(response.data.hubs[0]));
          dispatch(setMCUCondo(response.data.hubs[1]));
          dispatch(setMCUOffice(response.data.hubs[2]));
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log("miss");
            alert("Email or Password is wrong!");
        });
      };

  return (
    <>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(getJwt)}>
              <input placeholder='Email Address' className='form-control login_form' {...register('email')} />
              <div className="login_password_section">
                <input placeholder='Password' className='form-control login_form'  />
                <span
                    onClick={togglePassword}
                    role="presentation"
                    className="password_reveal"
                    >
                </span>
              </div>
            </form>

    </>

  );
}
export default Login;
```

stores/mcu.js

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  mcuhouse: '',
  mcucondo: '',
  mcuoffice: '',
};

const slice = createSlice({
  name: "mcu",
  initialState,
  reducers: {

    setMCUHouse: (state, action) => {
      return Object.assign({}, state, { mcuhouse: action.payload })
    },
    setMCUCondo: (state, action) => {
      return Object.assign({}, state, { mcucondo: action.payload })
    },
    setMCUOffice: (state, action) => {
      return Object.assign({}, state, { mcuoffice: action.payload })
    },

  }
});

export default slice.reducer;

export const { setMCUHouse, setMCUCondo, setMCUOffice,  } = slice.actions;
```

DiscoverCondo.js

```
  const url = useSelector(state => state.mcu.mcucondo);
  console.log(url)
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any obvious issues. Think you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue we could inspect live?

Comment: The issue *appears* to be caused by this line: `const url = useSelector(state => state.mcu.mcucondo);` (*you didn't include the complete `DiscoverCondo` file code so we can't tell what line 46 is*). Can you [edit] the post to share a more complete [mcve] that includes `DiscoverCondo` and shows how you are configuring the store, namely how the reducers are combined to form the state tree?

Comment: thank you for comment. line 46 is const url = useSelector(state => state.mcu.mcucondo);

Comment: Then it seems that `state.mcu` is undefined. Can you share how you combine the reducers and configure the store?

Comment: If I misunderstand something, I'm sorry but you mean     setMCUCondo: (state, action) => {
      return Object.assign({}, state, { mcucondo: action.payload })
    },?

Comment: No, I'm referring to where you import the reducer function exported from `stores/mcu.js` and  create the Redux store object. Sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: now I understand what you mean. I upload my answer. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

According to [RTK document](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/typescript),

you should set `configureStore()` like this.

**app/store.js**

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import mcuReducer from '...';
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    mcu: mcuReducer,
  },
});
// ...
```

Comment: Is this just a hunch or did you see something in the OP's post that indicated how they setup/configured their Redux store was an issue? OP default exports `mcuReducer`, so I think your code will have issue with `import * as mcuReducer from '...';` when it goes to create the store reducer.

Comment: @DrewReese There is not enough evidence, so I have to guess. 
First, OP shows error message, and it said there is no `mcu.mcucondo`. 
Second, OP's redux actions code looks okay to me. 

So, I guess OP might not configure store properly.

Comment: If there's not enough evidence, details, or context, then the post/question isn't really answerable.

Comment: I just propose one possibility, and If it isn't relative to the answer, I will delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I forget to update stores/index.js

I edit like this then go through

**stores/index.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

import mcuReducer from "./mcu";

import { save, load } from "redux-localstorage-simple"


const reducer = combineReducers({
  mcu:mcuReducer
});

const store = configureStore(
  { reducer,
    preloadedState: load(),
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(save()), },
  );

export default store;
```